# Printing only specific values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary , with 400 elements in it. They are of the form :

```
{'candidate 1' : 1, 'candidate 2' : 0, 'candidate 3' :0, 'candidate 4' :1}
```

and so on for about 400 values, I want to print the candidate id whose values in the dictionary are 1. The value takes either 0 (absent) or 1 (present).

I tried using `dict.values()` function and tried to loop it around and print only the value where `dict.value == 1`. But it's only printing the first value and not iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
dict_ = {'candidate 1' : 1, 'candidate 2' : 0, 'candidate 3' :0, 'candidate 4' :1}

print(*(k for k, v in dict_.items() if v))
```

**Output:**

```
candidate 1 candidate 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop to print

```py
d = {'candidate 1' : 1, 'candidate 2' : 0, 'candidate 3' :0, 'candidate 4' :1}
for k,v in d.items():
    if v == 1:
        print(k)
        
# candidate 1
# candidate 4
```

Use a comprehension to get a list

```py
[k for k,v in d.items() if v==1]
# ['candidate 1', 'candidate 4']
```